# How can i resolve the "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error" in my web service app on glassfish?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, glassfish

I have deployed a web app including an EJB (RESTFul web service) from Netbwans 8 into Glassfish 4. This includes a cross origin resource sharing filter.  I am getting the "HTTP Status 500 - Internal Server Error" error in the browser when i try to view the output of the web service (directly from the web service path, not from a client per se).  I saw in a forum that i might try un-checking a Jersey option in my project properties in Netbeans but i see no such option.  The only thing I've found in the logs is:

```
Info:   WELD-000900 2.0.0 (SP1)
Warning:   Class 'javax.ejb.PostActivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
Warning:   Class 'javax.ejb.PrePassivate' not found, interception based on it is not enabled
Info:   Registering the Jersey servlet application, named com.mycompany.enterprisesample.service.ApplicationConfig, at the servlet mapping /webresources/*, with the Application class of the same name.


Aug 21, 2014 11:31:10 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Aug 21, 2014 11:31:10 AM com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.BundleProvisioner$DefaultCustomizer getLocations
WARNING: Skipping entry  because it is not an absolute URI.
Registered com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishRuntime@5c8edb94 in service registry.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
<jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
```

line of code in the `domain.xml` file at `glassfish4\glassfish\domains\domain1\config\domain.xml` folder

inside `<java-config> </java-config>` tag as :-

```
<java-config>
.
.
<jvm-options>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</jvm-options>
</java-config>
```

Note:- add the above line of code at the last of the –D..... code of the domain.xml file. Adding it at random position may not gurantee that this will work.